# How to use Git LFS with Travis-CI (error building R data package)

Tags: r, travis-ci, git-lfs

I have an R package building on Travis-ci (private repo, so I can't directly share link).  I am also using Git LFS. I get the following error messagae from travis:

```
Warning in checkRdaFiles(Sys.glob(c(file.path(ddir, "*.rda"), file.path(ddir,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in checkRdaFiles(Sys.glob(c(file.path(ddir, "*.rda"), file.path(ddir,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in checkRdaFiles(Sys.glob(c(file.path(ddir, "*.rda"), file.path(ddir,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
Error in if (any(update)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Execution halted
The command "R CMD build  ." failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

Those errors are from `tools::checkRdaFiles()`, and you can find the R checking procedure at those lines [Here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/library/tools/R/build.R#L643-L659). When I run those same lines on my local machine, I don't get any warnings, and `update` is `FALSE`.

On my machine, the package builds fine.

My .travis.yml:

```
language: r
sudo: required
warnings_are_errors: false
```

Note, I also tried an older .yaml (style one would use before `language: r` was supported).

I think the problem is occurring because Travis CI cannot find the actual binary files; on GitHub, those large binaries are just 3 lines of text. That would probably result in the warnings.

Is this a problem related to Git LFS? Can I get Travis to pass my R package if I use Git LFS for my private repo?

Comment: Maybe you should update to [native R Travis support](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/)?

Comment: Can you also clarify where in the build that error occurs? If it's not in your package, it's probably related to one of the packages you're loading (or a temporary bug in R devel itself).

Comment: @Thomas I added some context to the question. I can post full logs somewhere if you'd like. I think the warnings might be because I have .RData files in data/ that were encoded to ASCII with `stringi::stri_enc_toascii`, and in a lot of cases the non-ascii characters became the `\032` code, which is just `NA`. But this is a guess (so the encoding might appear non-ASCII). Note that I already check to ensure all the .RData files had optimal compression. Anyway, that's my guess for those warnings. I don't know if the error is related or not.

Comment: Here's the source of the error message: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/library/tools/R/build.R#L645-L659 You should be able to run `checkRdaFiles()` on your `/data` directory to identify the source of the error.

Comment: Are you explicitly downloading the files with git-lfs on travis?  As far as I know travis doesn't have any built in git-lfs support.  I've had to install git-lfs on travis and then run `git lfs init` followed by a `git lfs pull` in order to get it to actually download the files.  If you don't do that you'll just have the stubs.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried unsuccessfully to integrate git-lfs into my travis-ci build structure and I ran into your same issue.

The issue here is that travis does not yet fully support git-lfs in all cases.  Like you, I would run the lfs commands but it would not download the binaries to the container.

I have not seen any changes recently from Travis about improvements to their git-lfs implementation but until their support gets better, I cant use it and would anticipate these issues.